# How do I install non-free drivers and codecs without an Internet connection?

Tags: installation, drivers, offline, codecs

I have installed ubuntu 10.10 on my pc. I dont have internet connection.

Now i haven't installed third party software like for music, video, graphics, display. So how do i do that?

Please help me.

Comment: See Also: [How can I install software offline?](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/667)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/offline-ubuntu-updater-keryx-hits-1-0/). This program allows you to download packages from one computer, save them in a USB drive and install them on another computer which hasn't got internet. That way you could install the mp3 codecs, or the graphics drivers you need. Good luck!

Comment: Why not link straight to the [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) website? The blog post you chose is just a news article.

Comment: For further explanation of the program, I thought that would be better, and it contains the link to the keryx website. Sorry if that confuses a little.